# Given functionname() is not a function

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a following line of codes. I am confused why I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: checkDistance is not a function" as error.

When I simply use function checkDistance(a, b) it is working fine. But with my below code I get that error.

Can anybody tell me what is my mistake?

```
var gjLayer = L.geoJson(testCities, {
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        var features = feature.geometry;
        var dist = checkDistance(features.coordinates[1], features.coordinates[0]);

        content = '<div class="container"><div class="row">'+dist+'<span>Name:</span>'+feature.properties.name+'</div></div>';
        layer.bindPopup(content);
    }
});


var checkDistance = function(lat1, lon1) {
   ...
   ...
   return
}
```

Comment: because it's function expression and has to be defined before usage

Comment: @HikmatG.you mean I have to define checkDistance function above.. Thank you. I just know it :)

Comment: you can also convert it to normal function declaration and will be fine even after usage

Comment: @HikmatG. which way is better?

Comment: if I don't have any specific reason to use function expression, I go with normal declaration.

Comment: Replace `var checkDistance = function(lat1, lon1)` with `function checkDistance(lat1, lon1)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
function checkDistance(lat1, lon1) {
    ...
    ...
    return
}
```

This will resolved your error. It is behaving because of hoisting.
Your using function before declaration.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to define `checkDistance` as a function expression, define it before `gjLayer` or you can use function declaration like below:

```
function checkDistance() {
  ...
}
```

Read [Hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)

Answer (score 1):

Please have look on basics of Hoisting.  Now in below Code snippet will not get "Uncaught TypeError: checkDistance is not a function". Always define the  function expression before use .

```js
function checkDistance(lat1, lon1) {
   
  
   return ;
}

var gjLayer = L.geoJson(testCities, {
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        var features = feature.geometry;
        var dist = checkDistance(features.coordinates[1], features.coordinates[0]);

        content = '<div class="container"><div class="row">'+dist+'<span>Name:</span>'+feature.properties.name+'</div></div>';
        layer.bindPopup(content);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare Your Variables At the Top !
Hoisting is (to many developers) an unknown or overlooked behavior of JavaScript.

If a developer doesn't understand hoisting, programs may contain bugs (errors).

To avoid bugs, always declare all variables at the beginning of every scope.

Since this is how JavaScript interprets the code, it is always a good rule.

Answer (score 0):

checkDistance = function(lat1, lon1){
 ...
 ...
 return
}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Chnage `var checkDistance = function(lat1, lon1)` with `function checkDistance(lat1, lon1)`
.Your problem will be resolve.You are getting becouse of hoistings.